# Show there is a $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $x\in \mathcal{C}$, $\{y:|x-y|<\epsilon\}\subseteq \mathcal{U}.$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a closed, bounded subset of the real line and $\mathcal{U}$ an open set containing $\mathcal{C}$. Show there is a $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $x\in \mathcal{C}$, $$\{y:|x-y|<\epsilon\}\subseteq \mathcal{U}.$$

This results seems trivial, since I have been using this fact with my other problems. But how to prove why it works is a different story. Can I get some assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c \in C$, define $d(c)=\inf_{x \in U^c} |c-x|$. It is fairly straightforward to show that $d$ is continuous (in fact
$|d(c)-d(c')| \le |c-c'|$).

Since $U$ is open, if $c \in C$, we see that $d(c) >0$.

Let $m=\min_{c \in C} d(c)$, since $C$ is compact and $d$ is continuous, the
$\min$ is attained at some $c^* \in C$ and hence $m = d(c^*) >0$.

Now choose $\epsilon = m$, note that if $c \in C$ and $x \notin U$, then $|c-x| \ge m$, hence if
$|c-x|< \epsilon = m$ and $c \in C$ then $x \in U$.

Answer (score 1):

$C\subset U$. For any $c$ in $C$ there is a $r_c>0$ such that $B(c,2r_c)\subset U$.

The collection $\mathscr U = \{B(c,r_c):c\in C\}$ is an open covering of $C$, which is compact, so there is a finite subcovering, i.e., $C\subset B(c_1,r_{c_1}) \cup \ldots\cup B(c_n,r_{c_n})$. Choose $r =\min \{r_{c_k}:k=1,\ldots, n\}>0$. We claim that our election of $r$ works.

To show that $B(c,r)\subset U$ for $c$ in $C$.

Let $c$ in $C$, there is $j\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ such that $c\in B(c_j,r_{c_j})$. Now for $y$ in $B(c,r)$, we have that

$$d(y,c_j)\le d(y,c)+d(c,c_j)<r+r_{c_j}\le 2 r_{c_j},$$

so $y\in B(c_{j},2r_{2_j})\subset U$. Then $B(c,r)\subset U$.